# How to iterate through values of a dictionary until there is no more values (reached the end of the dictionary)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Let's say I have a dictionary such as

```
d = {'Item 1': [3,4,5,3], 'Item 2': [2,3,4], 'Item 3': [5,34,75,35,65]}
```

What I want to do is calculate the summation of two elements in the list and add them to a total. Such as for Item 1, I would want to do 3 + 4, 4 + 5, 5 + 3, and stop once I have reached the last value of the dictionary. Similarly, I want to do this with all the values in the dictionary and add them to a grand total.

Comment: Do you mean the summation of all *distinct* elements in the list? Otherwise, for item 1, you would count 3+4, 3+5 twice, as well as 3+3. In that scenario, it might be more prudent to use a `set` rather than a `list`

Comment: There are dozens if not hundreds of articles on iterating python dictionaries.  Google "how to iterate a python dictionary" and read up on the basics, then post back here with your code if you are still running into trouble.

Comment: yes I mean the summation of all distinct elements such as 3 + 4, 4 + 5, 5 + 3, including both the 3's in item 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have Python 3.10, you can use `itertools.pairwise`:

```
from itertools import pairwise, chain

d = {
    'Item 1': [3,4,5,3],
    'Item 2': [2,3,4],
    'Item 3': [5,34,75,35,65]
}

for key, numbers in d.items():
    s = sum(chain.from_iterable(pairwise(numbers)))
    print(f"{key}: {s}")
```

Output:

```
Item 1: 24
Item 2: 12
Item 3: 358
```

---

Alternatively, if you don't have Python 3.10, you can define your own `pairwise`:

```
from itertools import tee, chain

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    yield from zip(a, b)
```

---

If you just want a total sum:

```
total_sum = sum(sum(chain.from_iterable(pairwise(nums))) for nums in d.values())
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm on 3.9 is there any alternative to doing this in Python 3.9?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through a dictionary with a `for` loop just like you would with a list, iterable, tuple, or set:

```
for item in d:
    print(item)
```

Adding up the paired items in each list that is in the dictionary is more complicated. You would have to find the length of the list, which I don't know how to do. However, if you wanted to just sum up *all* the items in each list (so that `[2, 7, 1]` becomes 10), you could do this. Using the dictionary from your question:

```
d = {
    'Item 1': [3,4,5,3],
    'Item 2': [2,3,4],
    'Item 3': [5,34,75,35,65]
}

sums = [] # blank list
for list in d:
    n = 0 # used as a local variable
    for item in list:
        n += item
    sums.append(n) # put n on the end of sums
print(sums)
```

Note that this is ***not*** adding the adjacent pairs in the lists, instead, it prints a list containing the sums of the lists in `d`. I hope my answer can help.

Comment: yes, this works. Just to add on lets assume we want to use some function on two elements which we cant just hard code like how since its summing we can just add each element. Suppose we want to use a function that uses the current element and the next element (if it exists) how would that work?